# Get all combinations from N arrays

Tags: arrays, perl, combinations

I have array of arrays.

```
@a=([1,2,3],['b','r','g'],['L','X']);
```

And want to have this result:

```
@b=(
[1,'b','L'],[1,'b','X'],
[1,'r','L'],[1,'r','X'],
[1,'g','L'],[1,'g','X'],

[2,'b','L'],[2,'b','X'],
[2,'r','L'],[2,'r','X'],
[2,'g','L'],[2,'g','X'],

[3,'b','L'],[3,'b','X'],
[3,'r','L'],[3,'r','X'],
[3,'g','L'],[3,'g','X'],
)
```

My input array @a have from 2 to 6 nested arrays

Dont know how to find this function on cpan.

Comment: Use http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Math%3A%3ACombinatorics

Comment: Yes, I saw that. But its no combine, no permutation, no derange. And that is all from that lib.

Comment: There is also [Set::CrossProduct](http://search.cpan.org/~bdfoy/Set-CrossProduct-1.95/lib/Set/CrossProduct.pm)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
use Algorithm::Loops qw( NestedLoops );
my @b; NestedLoops(\@a, sub { push @b, [ @_ ] });
```

Answer (score 1):

Why cpan?

```
use strict; use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
my @a=([1,2,3],['b','r','g'],['L','X']);

my @b;
foreach my $i (@{$a[0]}){
    foreach my $c (@{$a[1]}){
        foreach my $k (@{$a[2]}){
            push @b, [$i, $c, $k];
        }
    }
}

print Dumper(\@b);
```

Comment: Its not always 3 dimensions. I have @a as input, and it have from 2 to 6 arrays inside.